# Is "Life is tired" correct English?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

The sentence was found in the lyrics of a song from a Dutch-born Chinese singer so given her origins I am not entirely sure it is correct English.

On the other hand the seemingly correct expression "Life is tiring" may sound a bit too grave/over the top in a lyrical context? Again I defer to the crushing verdict of you native speakers.

Comment: In lyrics one is allowed substantial "poetic license".  "Life is tired" is not incorrect syntax, and it could validly convey a metaphorical meaning different from the more idiomatic "life is tiring".  It would depend on the intent of the writer.

Comment: It could also be some sort of ellipsis/reversal for "I am tired of life."

Comment: The syntax is fine. The meaning is hard to guess, but meaning is not generally required in poetry.

Answer (score 1):

Well *life is tired* would mean that the concept of life itself is tired — a slightly odd and unusual sort of personification. *Life is tiring*, as you suggested, is a lot more common of a phrase — it implies that *life* has the ability to *make one tired*. I'll let you figure out which one she meant...